# Multiple t-tests

Tags: multiple-comparisons

Suppose we have some baseline data $X_1$ with $n$ observations and some post-baseline data $X_2$ with $n$ observations. We want to compare whether the post-baseline data differs significantly in mean from the baseline data.

Would using multiple t-tests mean that we would need to make $n^2$ comparisons? That is, we compare each data point from post-baseline to every other baseline data point? Would this have a high Type 1 error? Should we be looking at the family-wise error rate?

Comment: Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two variables, you'd only carry out one test, regardless of sample size. I don't see why you suggested there would be $n^2$ tests.

Comment: A comparison of a single baseline point to a single post-baseline point couldn't be done with a t-test even if you wanted to- t-tests are meant for comparing two samples that each have a size larger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

The sample size has nothing to do with the number of tests that you would run. You only need 1 test. Are the data paired? You may need a paired $t$ test, but that's still only 1 test.

If you have $n$ treatments, you would have $n(n-1)/2$ individual $t$ tests to run and should use Tukey's method to control for experimentwise error.